# counting views sometimes work, sometimes not counting

Tags: python, django

it's weird. sometimes it counts, sometimes it doesn't. I don't see anything wrong with the code, here's my code.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    with_votes = PostVoteCountManager() #nothing to do with views
    objects = models.Manager() #nothing to do with views
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


    @property
    def update_view(self):
        self.views = self.views + 1
        return self.save()
```

and in my html I simply did

```
 <small class="text-muted ">{{ post.views }}view{{ post.views|pluralize }} | </small><span>
```

my views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostListByMostViewedView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/mostviewed_home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-views']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Comment: Why is update_view a property? Do you call/access update_view in your Django view?

Comment: @Krukas no I don't have anything for counting pages in view

Comment: @Krukas so every time post is used view is updated so it make sense to me view to be in model

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'post is used' like used in a view to be shown or just loaded. I think the logic is better in the Django view, because I think that's the only time you want to update it. So the view that returns your post, there you can update your views counter.

Comment: i mean like every time post page is opened, view is incremented. so do you think i should put that in my post detail view? I still think the logic should be in models.py

Comment: You could keep the function in your model, but you still need to call it from your Django view. Also updating your view count this will get incorrect counter if multiple people open the page at the same time (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY_2gElt3SA)

Comment: it was working fine till about 3hrs ago so weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would suggest you to make a detail_post view and write logic in
>   views.py to increase the view.
>
> **For example:**

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
post.views += 1
post.save()
```

> Try this if you are using class based views

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        self.object.count += 1
        self.object.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).get(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm using class based view (for list and detail view) I'm not sure how I can coordinate that with my views. is there a way to do it in model?cuz it worked a day ago

Answer (score 0):

In your view you will need to call `update_view`. If you don't the `view` property of your instance won't get updated.
For instance with a function based view:

```
def your_view(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    post.update_view()
    context={'post': post}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

for a class based view you could:

```
class YourView(View):

    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = context['post']
        post.update_view()
        context['post'] = post

        return context
```

Comment: I'm using class based view (for list and detail view) I'm not sure how I can coordinate that with my views. is there a way to do it in model?cuz it worked a day ago

Comment: I added a possibility for CBV, but the general idea is that the method you created will need to be called each time you want to increment your counter

Comment: it says 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @rosababy maybe removing the parentheses post.update_view

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately, it only increment once. when i refresh no increment